# How to use randint for strings in Python 3?

Tags: python

I am making a mini version of Russian Rullet. 
I have a code which gives me a random number from 1 - 36 but I also need to ask my program to randomly give either Red or Black?

```
from random import randint

print(randint(1,36))
print (randint ('Red', 'Black'))
```

Comment: you can use 0,1, *0* means Red, *1* means Black.

Comment: This sounds like regular roulette. Isn't Russian roulette the thing where you have a revolver with one bullet loaded and take turns shooting yourself and hoping not to die?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend this, but

```
from random import randint
print(["Red","Black"][randint(0,1)])
```

Comment: I like your way

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 a = randint(0,1)

 color = 'Red' if a == 1 else color == 'Black'

 print(color)
```